# ($Inbox) or ($Draft) views does not exist in lotus domino database

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying to create c# application for reading mails from lotus domino. I can connect to server but when i try to access to views i can see all the views except ($Inbox, ($Draft) or ($Sent).

as result db.getview("($Inbox)") returns null. I cannot understand why they don't show up

My test domino server is domino social 9

**Edit:** My problem is that i was trying to connect to "names.nsf" instead of user's nsf file. once i replace correct name now i'm able to get ($Inbox) etc.

Comment: Great that you found a solution to your problem. Maybe you should delete the question (or add an answer to the question).

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that i was trying to connect to "names.nsf" instead of user's nsf file. once i replace correct name now i'm able to get ($Inbox) etc.